# Rsync only creates directory permission (rwx------) with --relative option?

Tags: rsync

I am running a rsync command like this on host1:
[usr@host1] **rsync -a -relative -no-implied-dirs folder1/folder2 usr@host2:/**
where folder1/folder2 does not exist on host2.

By -relative option, folder1 is created on host2, but it does not have the same permission as the one from host1. Say I have permission rwxrwxrwx for folder1 on host1 but I will only have rwx------ for folder1 on host2.

How can I let folder1 have the same permission? Note that I may have a much complicated file structure so it is not feasible to manually do a 777 on all folder manually by chmod..

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't copy the same permissions as the source, using the **--chmod** option allows you to explicitly set directory and file permissions on the destination. For example

`--chmod=D775,F664`

sets destination directories to 755 and files to 664.

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure your rsync runs as root.

Also try using below flags -

> rsync -avz source destination